# How to change the status bar icon while service is running

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-statusbar

I want to change the notification `smallIcon` in the status bar while a foreground service is running, depending on the status the service gathers, namely "mute" or "unmute".

What is needed to display alternate `smallIcons` from the `res.drawable` resouce?

In the initialize method of the service class, I currently set the mute icon as follows, but I don't know how to change it after the service was started:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        this, NOTE_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mute_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Calm: Running")
        .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.calm_close_txt))
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentIntent(stopIntent);

startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to hold a reference to the `NotificationCompat.Builder`. Then use the `notify(int id, Notification notification)` method of `NotificationManagerCompat`.

Example:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;

private void startNotif(){
    notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
        this, NOTE_CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.mute_icon)
        .setContentTitle("Calm: Running")
        .setContentText(this.getString(R.string.calm_close_txt))
        .setOngoing(true)
        .setContentIntent(stopIntent);
    
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}

private void changeIcon(int resID, Context context){
    notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(resID);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is to just create a new notification with a new icon, so it'll replace the old one.

**EDIT:**
Here's a sample code for creating a new notification every time a button is clicked with a sample logic based on a boolean variable called `indicator`.

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Create the notification builder object
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(v.getContext(), NOTE_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(indicator ? R.drawable.icon1 : R.drawable.icon2)   //TODO: change this line with your logic
                .setContentTitle("Your notification title here")
                .setContentText("Your notificiation text here")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
//                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)    //pendingIntent to fire when the user taps on it
                .setAutoCancel(true);   //autoremove the notificatin when the user taps on it

        //show the notification constructed above
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(v.getContext());
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

        indicator = !indicator; //switch icon indicator (just for demonstration)
    }
});
```

Comment: How would I do that? Please note that I use startForeground()

Comment: Thanks, yet my service status does not change on a button click but it is detected by the service as I described in my question.

Comment: @monok, the button click that I've used is just for demonstration purpose, so you should create a new notification similarly based on the events that you have.